# ImportError: No module named 'accounts' - Heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-toolbelt

When trying to deploy to Heroku, I am receiving the following error:

```
22:06:03 web.1   |      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
22:06:03 web.1   |    File "/Users/XXX/.envs/carla/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
22:06:03 web.1   |      app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
22:06:03 web.1   |    File "/Users/XXX/.envs/carla/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
22:06:03 web.1   |      module = import_module(entry)
22:06:03 web.1   |    File "/Users/XXX/.envs/carla/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
22:06:03 web.1   |      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
22:06:03 web.1   |  ImportError: No module named 'accounts'
```

**Installed apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_summernote',
    'widget_tweaks',

    'accounts',
    ...
]
```

**Project structure:**

```
- carla/
    - carla/
        - accounts/
        - static/
        - templates/
    - config
        - settings/
        - __init__.py
        - urls.py
        - wsgi.py
    - manage.py
    - Procfile
    - requirements.txt
    ...
```

Would anyone know why Heroku isn't able to find my `'accounts'` app? It works fine locally, and is obviously in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have wrong project hierarchy, not sure how you makes it works on local. You have two carla folds which should have only one carla, the second one should be replaced with accounts, otherwise in your settings.py file you should put carla.accounts instead of accounts in the installed_apps.